# Google OAuth2: Required parameter is missing: grant_type

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have tried just about everything, read every StackOverflow post on this issue but I still can't get it to work. Interestingly enough, I am able to get **200 OK** response when sending a POST request via DHC REST API Client (Google Chrome app).

```
  var url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
  var params = querystring.stringify({
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code: req.body.code,
    client_id: req.body.clientId,
    client_secret: 'HIDDEN',
    redirect_uri: req.body.redirectUri
  });
  params = querystring.unescape(params); // doesn't work with or without string escaping

  request.post(url + '?' + params, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
  });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're sending the request as a POST but the parameters as GET.

Comment: @BenFortune **/faceplam**. I knew I was doing something idiotic. Thanks for catching my mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @BenFortune has already mentioned, I was sending `GET` parameters as a `POST` request. It's amazing such a trivial thing has gone unnoticed after trying to figure it out for over an hour.

Now, I blame inconsistencies across OAuth providers for this. In the same application I am doing a `GET` request to **Facebook** to obtain `access_token`: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token. But **Google** expects a `POST` request to obtain `access_token`: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

#### Correct version:

```
  var url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
  var payload = {
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code: req.body.code,
    client_id: req.body.clientId,
    client_secret: 'HIDDEN',
    redirect_uri: req.body.redirectUri
  };

  request.post(url, { form: payload }, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
  });
```

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same error. I tried what you did and I receive this error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400. `

Comment: omg, fu*ing postman, I was inserting url params instead of POST params...

Answer (score 0):

Check the request Encoding.

in my case i was sending .json and was .url

Using Alamofire 3.0