# How to get Access_token from google?

Tags: angularjs, rest-client

I am calling:

- URL-https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
- METHOD-POST
- BODY-

  ```
  {
     "client_id": "832123433433-9r28oattkl7rbaa5fsp3stfmhcvvlolf.apps.googleusercontent.com",
     "redirect_uri"  : "https://www.inka.com/oauth2callback",
     "client_secret"  :"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
     "grant_type" : "authorization_code"
  }
  ```

It show the following Error

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"
}
```

Can any one tell me where I am wrong???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google OAuth2: Required parameter is missing: grant\_type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030312/google-oauth2-required-parameter-is-missing-grant-type) - `Required parameter is missing: grant_type` - that seems quite self-explanatory, [add a `grant_type` parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25042391/1270789).

Comment: This [similar question][1] explains the answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030312/google-oauth2-required-parameter-is-missing-grant-type